# Vue, SPA, Laravel. Erro with response

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, response, single-page-application

I am getting an error when I request. Оn the backend side there is a check that the name length is at least 3 characters. The response from the server is correct. but when I try to display an error, the message comes out saying that the answer was not found.

```
async saveBoard(id, index) {
      await this.API.put("/boards/" + id, {
        name: this.boards[index].name,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          alert(response.data.message);
          this.boards[index].etitable = !this.boards[index].etitable;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

when I try to output error.response.date to the console, I get an error that response is not defined.

How can I solve this problem, why does axios not see the response from the server and the error code?

Answer (score 0):

Error code must be in your `catch` You can't reach error message in `then`.

You are probably see error in your console right now

Comment: yes i know that. but when I try to display the result of error 422, it turns out that the response was not found at all. although the response in the console comes with an error 422.

Answer (score 0):

````
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        if (error.response.status == 401 || error.response.status == 419) {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if (token) {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
            }

            const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
            if (user) {
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
            }
            router.push('/login');
        } else {
            if (error.response.status == 403) {
                router.push('/');
            }
        }

        
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });```


I added a return to the interceptors function. Problem solved thanks for your help.
````